# Multiple plots according to checkboxGroupInput

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create an easy application with R shiny. However I could not get the desired output I want. I am neither experienced in shiny  nor  an expert of R.   Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel("deneme"),
  checkboxGroupInput("plots", "draw plots:", 
                 choices=list("histogram", "qq","both"), 
                 selected="histogram"),
  sidebarPanel(
    numericInput("mean", "rn mean", value=seq(0:5), min=0, max=5),
    numericInput("sd","standart deviation",value=seq(0:5),min=0,max=5),
    numericInput("n", " number of observations ", value=seq(30,50))
    ),

  mainPanel(
    textOutput("text1"),
    fluidRow(splitLayout(cellWidths = c("60%", "40%"), 
                     plotOutput("graph1"), plotOutput("graph2")))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  norm<-reactive({
    set.seed(6)
    rnorm(input$n,mean=input$mean,sd=input$sd)
    })  

  output$text1<-renderText({
                    paste("A random normal distrubution of", 
                          input$n, "observations is generated with parameters mean",
                          input$mean,"and standart deviation", input$sd)
    })

  output$graph1<-renderPlot({    
    if(identical(input$plots,"histogram")){
    req(norm())
    hist(norm())
    }  
  })

  output$graph2<- renderPlot({ 
    if(identical(input$plots,"qq")) {
      req(norm())
      qqnorm(norm(), pch = 1, frame = FALSE)
      qqline(norm(), col = "steelblue", lwd = 2)
      }
  })

  observe({
    if(identical(input$plots,"both")) { 
      req(norm())
      output$graph1<- renderPlot({
        hist(norm())
        })
      output$graph2<- renderPlot({
        qqnorm(norm(), pch = 1, frame = FALSE)
        qqline(norm(), col = "steelblue", lwd = 2) 
        })
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I want the plot layout change dynamically according to  selection of `checkboxGroupInput`. When I click `histogram` or `qq` I want it to plot an unsplit frame,  into only one plotting frame. Whereas when I click `both` I want the plots  to be  seen together in a split frame of two rows. When unclicked the layout must be reset to one frame again. I know I am not doing it right by splitting the layout in `ui` first. I saw something about `renderUI` function but could not understand how it works. Thanks in advance.
Also I got some error related to if statement:

> Warning in if (!is.na(attribValue)) { :
>   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
>   Warning in charToRaw(enc2utf8(text)) :
>   argument should be a character vector of length 1
>   all but the first element will be ignored

Comment: The warning messages are because you have specified multiple values for the `value` arguments of the `numericInput` ui's. They should only be a single value.

Comment: thank you. you are right again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a start, you don't need the observer, you can just add an `if` statement to each `renderPlot`.

**Update:** The trick to getting the plots to update dynamically is to assign them into a list and then render the list of plots with `renderUI`, the only caveat to this is that I am unaware of a way to get these plots to render side-by-side at the moment, it probably has something to do with adding some div tags...

**Update 2:** To get the plots side by side we just need to wrap the `plotOutput` in `column`

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel("deneme"),
  checkboxGroupInput("plots", "draw plots:", 
                     choices=list("histogram", "qq"), 
                     selected="histogram"),
  sidebarPanel(
    numericInput("mean", "rn mean", value=1, min=0, max=5),
    numericInput("sd","standart deviation",value=1,min=0,max=5),
    numericInput("n", " number of observations ", value=30)
  ),

  mainPanel(
    textOutput("names"),
    textOutput("text1"),
    fluidRow(uiOutput("plot_list"))
  )
 )


server <- function(input, output) {
  norm<-reactive({
    set.seed(6)
    rnorm(input$n,mean=input$mean,sd=input$sd)
  })  

  output$text1<-renderText({
    paste("A random normal distribution of", 
          input$n, "observations is generated with parameters mean",
          input$mean,"and standart deviation", input$sd)
  })

  output$histogram <- renderPlot({    
    req(norm())
    if("histogram" %in% input$plots){
      hist(norm())
    }
  })

  output$qq <- renderPlot({ 
    req(norm())
    if("qq" %in% input$plots){
      qqnorm(norm(), pch = 1, frame = FALSE)
      qqline(norm(), col = "steelblue", lwd = 2)
    }
  })

  output$plot_list <- renderUI({
    plot_output_list <- lapply(input$plots, 
                               function(plotname) {
                                 column(width=5, plotOutput(plotname)) ##wrap the plotOutput in column to render side-by-side
                               })

    # Convert the list to a tagList - this is necessary for the list of items
    # to display properly.
    do.call(tagList, plot_output_list)
  })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I still get same error related to if statement with your definition too  .  I am looking for no blank space solution   by updating plotting frame after clicking each check box  . The ui must change according to selection of check boxes. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Thank you without splitting the layout it gives me what I want with dynamically rendering ui. however seeing side by side is more important for me. Also I am planning to add another plots which will make things more complex :) In this one I want to divide the first row into two columns and others will be plotted into only a row. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a single `plotOutput` and use `mfrow` to split it into two panels, like this:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel("deneme"),
  radioButtons("plots", "draw plots:", 
               choices=list("histogram", "qq","both"), 
               selected="histogram"),
  sidebarPanel(
    numericInput("mean", "rn mean", value=seq(0:5), min=0, max=5),
    numericInput("sd","standart deviation",value=seq(0:5),min=0,max=5),
    numericInput("n", " number of observations ", value=seq(30,50))
  ),

  mainPanel(
    textOutput("text1"),
    plotOutput("graph")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  norm<-reactive({
    set.seed(6)
    rnorm(input$n,mean=input$mean,sd=input$sd)
  })  

  output$text1<-renderText({
    paste("A random normal distrubution of", 
          input$n, "observations is generated with parameters mean",
          input$mean,"and standart deviation", input$sd)
  })

  output$graph = renderPlot({
    if(input$plots == "both") {
      par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
    }
    if(is.element(input$plots, c("histogram", "both"))) {
      req(norm())
      hist(norm())
    }
    if(is.element(input$plots, c("qq", "both"))) {
      req(norm())
      qqnorm(norm(), pch = 1, frame = FALSE)
      qqline(norm(), col = "steelblue", lwd = 2)
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If you want two rows instead of two columns, just change `par(mfrow = c(1, 2))` to `par(mfrow = c(2, 1))`.

(I'm still getting the error on `if` too, but it doesn't seem to affect the functioning of the app, at least as far as the graphs are concerned.  I'm not sure where it's coming from.)

Comment: Thank you. this is  the desired output I want exactly. I thought to use `parmfrow()` but could not manage how. Yes, it does not affect the functioning of the app but errors are  still there. I did use if statements like this one before and did not get any errors .